# How get the value of drop down list with multiple option using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying for get all value of drop down list with multiple option

```
 <select name="select" multiple id="select">
 <option value="aa">aa</option>
 <option value="bb">bb</option>
 </select>
 <BR><BR>
 <input type=submit value="Print All" onClick="printAll()">
 <script>

  function printAll()
   {
     var selectedValues = $("#select").val();
     alert(selectedValues);
   }

  </script>
```

Any body help me?

Comment: this should work however you can find option which are selected

Comment: Change your `submit` to a button and do what @Cory mentioned

Comment: Use Each function of Jquery for print all option value.

Answer (score 3):

What you've done should work (eventually). `val()` will return an `Array` of selected option values, e.g.:

```
console.log(selectedValues); // [ "aa", "bb" ]
```

If you want to turn the array back into a string to display it, you might do:

```
alert(selectedValues.join(', ')); // "aa, bb"
```

But first you need to change your input type to `button` so your page isn't posting back:

```
<input type="button" value="Print All" onClick="printAll()">
```

Or, since you're using jQuery, do this the right way with an unobtrusive event binding (removing the inline `onClick` handler):

```
<input type="button" id="print" value="Print All">
```

And then add a `click` handler with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
      $('#print').click(function() {
          var selectedValues = $("#select").val();
          alert(selectedValues.join(', '));
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Click event is effect less since that button click would submit that form.. Page would be refreshed..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select option:selected').each(function(){
     console.log(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : What you have done should work, also you can try below jquery which gives you option values which are selected.

```
function printAll()
   {
     var selectedValues = new Array();
     $("#select option:selected").each(function(){
       selectedValues.push($(this).val());
     });
     alert(selectedValues);
    // for comma seperated values use 
    // alert(selectedValues.join(', '));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the button `type = "submit"` to `type = "button"` and give that button some id :

```
<input type="button" value="Print All" id="print">
```

and use this following jQuery code :-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#print').click(function()
    {

        var val = $("#select").val();
        alert(val);

    });

});
```

Working Demo :- **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/S3g7d/2/)**

Or you can do like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#print').click(function()
        {

            $('#select option:selected').each(function()
            {
               alert(this.value);
            });

        });

    });
```